# How do you find the average of particular numbers in a csv file?

Tags: python, loops, csv, math

```
with open('sortedsimpsons_episodes.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    print("Season 1")
    for idx,row in enumerate(csv_reader):
        if idx>=1 and idx<=13:
            print(f'"{row[1]}" is an episode in season {row[4]}, that has {row[7]} million views and an imdb rating of {row[9]}')

viewsAverage = round((30.3 + 30.4 + 27.6 + 33.5 + 31.2 + 27.1 + 26.7 + 25.4 + 20.2 + 27.4 + 28 + 27.1 + 27.5) / 13,2)
imdbAverage = round((7.4 + 8.3 + 7.9 + 7.5 + 7.8 + 7.9 + 8.2 + 7.8 + 7.8 + 7.6 + 7.7 + 8.1 + 7.5) / 13,2)
print("The average amount of views in season 1 is: "+str(viewsAverage)+ " million.")
print("The average imdb rating of season 1 is: " +str(imdbAverage))
csv_file.close()
```

CSV file:

```
"Krusty Gets Busted" is an episode in season 1, that has 30.4 million views and an imdb rating of 8.3.
"The Call of the Simpsons" is an episode in season 1, that has 27.6 million views and an imdb rating of 7.9.
"Life on the Fast Lane" is an episode in season 1, that has 33.5 million views and an imdb rating of 7.5.
"The Crepes of Wrath" is an episode in season 1, that has 31.2 million views and an imdb rating of 7.8.
"Some Enchanted Evening" is an episode in season 1, that has 27.1 million views and an imdb rating of 7.9.
"Simpsons Roasting on an Open Fire" is an episode in season 1, that has 26.7 million views and an imdb rating of 8.2.
"Bart the Genius" is an episode in season 1, that has 24.5 million views and an imdb rating of 7.8.
"There's No Disgrace Like Home" is an episode in season 1, that has 26.2 million views and an imdb rating of 7.8.
"Moaning Lisa" is an episode in season 1, that has 27.4 million views and an imdb rating of 7.6.
"The Telltale Head" is an episode in season 1, that has 28 million views and an imdb rating of 7.7.
"Bart the General" is an episode in season 1, that has 27.1 million views and an imdb rating of 8.1.
"Homer's Odyssey" is an episode in season 1, that has 27.5 million views and an imdb rating of 7.5.
"Bart Gets an "F"" is an episode in season 2, that has 33.6 million views and an imdb rating of 8.2.
"Two Cars in Every Garage and Three Eyes on Every Fish" is an episode in season 2, that has 26.1 million views and an imdb rating of 8.1.
"Dead Putting Society" is an episode in season 2, that has 25.4 million views and an imdb rating of 8.
"Bart the Daredevil" is an episode in season 2, that has 26.2 million views and an imdb rating of 8.4.
```

When the whole file is printed in python, it's long. It goes on for 27 seasons. I want to find the averages of the views and rating for each season and I only know how to do it manually as shown in the code above. The code works and prints exactly what I want, but doing it this way will take me forever. How do I find the average views of a season without inputting all the numbers manually?

Comment: What you posted doesn't look like a csv file...

Comment: I think they posted the output of the loop.

Comment: This is not a CSV file, but an image. Please, post a minimal sample of your file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dictionaries to store lists of imdb ratings, or viewers for each season.

Python has a nice default dictionary which you can use to automatically create empty lists for each season:

```
from collections import defaultdict

ratings = defaultdict(list)
viewings = defaultdict(list)

for row in csv_reader:
    season, viewing, rating = row[4], row[7], row[9]

    ratings[season].append(rating)
    viewings[season].append(viewing)
```

Then you can get the list of ratings, for example, and calculate the mean:

```
>>> from statistics import mean
>>> mean(ratings['season 1'])
7.807692307692307
```

Answer (score 0):

During your loop why not add to a total and divide by the count?

```
viewsTotal = 0
imdbTotal = 0
total = 0
with open('sortedsimpsons_episodes.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    print("Season 1")
    for idx, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
        if idx >= 1 and idx <= 13:
            viewsTotal += float(row[7])
            imdbTotal += float(row[9])
            total = idx
            print(f'"{row[1]}" is an episode in season {row[4]}, that has {row[7]} million views and an imdb rating of {row[9]}')
viewsAverage = round(viewsTotal / total,2)
imdbAverage = round(imdbTotal / total,2)
print("The average amount of views in season 1 is: "+str(viewsAverage)+ " million.")
print("The average imdb rating of season 1 is: " +str(imdbAverage))
```

Not sure if your lower prints and averages are supposed to be worked out after the csv_file loop. Also you do not need the .close() as 'with open()' closes the file when it is finished.

Answer (score 0):

To find the averages of the views and rating for each season, you first need to sort an group the row by seasons.

I make the assumption that:

- row[1] is the title,
- row[4] is the season,
- row[7] is the number of views,
- row[9] is the rate.

So, I imagine you have something like this (I have replaced the unknown values by `None`):

```
rows = [
    ('title1', None, None, None, 1, None, None, 30.4, None, 8.5),
    ('title2', None, None, None, 2, None, None, 27.5, None, 6.5),
    ('title3', None, None, None, 1, None, None, 40.2, None, 4.0),
    ('title4', None, None, None, 1, None, None, 21.9, None, 2.6),
]
```

To sort and group the rows and to extract the values from the rows, you can use `operator.itemgetter`, like this:

```
import operator

get_season = operator.itemgetter(4)
get_views = operator.itemgetter(7)
get_rate = operator.itemgetter(9)
```

With this in hand, you can calculate the means:

```
import itertools

rows.sort(key=get_season)
for season, group in itertools.groupby(rows, key=get_season):
    group = list(group)
    count = len(group)
    total_views = sum(get_views(row) for row in group)
    total_rate = sum(get_rate(row) for row in group)
    mean_views = total_views / count
    mean_rate = total_rate / count
    print(f"season {season} - views: {mean_views:.2f}, rate: {mean_rate:.2f}")
```

You get:

```
season 1 - views: 30.83, rate: 5.03
season 2 - views: 27.50, rate: 6.50
```

Like described in another answer you can also use  the statistics module:

```
import itertools
import statistics

rows.sort(key=get_season)
for season, group in itertools.groupby(rows, key=get_season):
    group = list(group)
    mean_views = statistics.mean(get_views(row) for row in group)
    mean_rate = statistics.mean(get_rate(row) for row in group)
    print(
        f"season {season} - views: {mean_views:.2f}, rate: {mean_rate:.2f}")
```

Comment: The first element of sequences are indexed with `0`, so `row[0]` is the title.

Answer (score 0):

Your input file isn't in valid csv format. However with a little scaffolding the avoid issues that would trip-up the built-in `csv` module, it can be used. The main trick is to consider the spaces in the the delimiter. This means the `csv.reader` would return something like this for each line of the file. The first line indicates the index of each item:

```
     0        1     2      3         4      5       6       7      8       9       10        11       12    13     14       15      16     17
['"title"', 'is', 'an', 'episode', 'in', 'season', '1,', 'that', 'has', '30.4', 'million', 'views', 'and', 'an', 'imdb', 'rating', 'of', '8.3.']
['"title"', 'is', 'an', 'episode', 'in', 'season', '1,', 'that', 'has', '27.6', 'million', 'views', 'and', 'an', 'imdb', 'rating', 'of', '7.9.']
```

This is useable except there's a couple of fields that have extra characters at the end like `.`, and `,` which prevents them from being valid Python literals. This is accomplished by removing the last character of those field strings.

The code:

```
from ast import literal_eval
from collections import namedtuple
import csv
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter, itemgetter
import itertools


# Data definition of fields.
FIELDS =     'title', 'season', 'views', 'rating' # Field names.
INDICES =       0,       6,        9,       17    # Index of each field.
TRUNCATE =               6,                 17    # Last char removal.

def parse(field):
    try:
        return literal_eval(field)  # Interpret as a Python literal.
    except Exception:
        return field # Assume it's an unquoted string.

# Create list or records made from fields of interest in csv file.
Record = namedtuple('Record', FIELDS)
records = []
with open('sortedsimpsons_episodes.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
    for row in csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=' '):
        for index in TRUNCATE:  # Strip trailing char from designated fields.
            row[index] = row[index][:-1]
        raw_data = itemgetter(*INDICES)(row)  # Raw string data in each field.
        # Convert raw field string data to desired types.
        values = (parse(field) for field in raw_data)
        records.append(Record(*values))

# Calculate and print statistics.
grouper = attrgetter('season')
records.sort(key=grouper)
for season, records in groupby(records, key=grouper):
    records = list(records)
    views_avg = sum(rec.views for rec in records) / len(records)
    imdb_avg = sum(rec.rating for rec in records) / len(records)
    print("Season {}:".format(season))
    print("  Average number of views: {:.2f} million".format(views_avg))
    print("  Average imdb rating: {:.2f}".format(imdb_avg))
```

Output:

```
Season 1:
  Average number of views: 28.10 million
  Average imdb rating: 7.84
Season 2:
  Average number of views: 27.82 million
  Average imdb rating: 8.17
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go, this works hundred percent:

```
import numpy as np
def get_avg_rating_and_views(df):
    avg_dict = {}
    i = 0
    for data in df["Field_name_to_scan"]:
      avg_dict[i] = []
      for d in data.split(): 
         try:
            float_val = float(d)
            if len(avg_dict[i]) < 2:
                avg_dict[i].append(float_val)
         except:
            pass
      i = i + 1


    views , imdb_ratings = list(zip(*avg_dict.values()))
    avg_view = np.average(views)
    print("Average View: ",avg_view)
    avg_imdb_ratings = np.average(imdb_ratings)
    print("Imdb average Rating", avg_imdb_ratings)

df = pd.read_csv("your_csv.csv")
get_avg_rating_and_views(df)
```

Basically, you need to go through every row in that specific column and fetch the two values. This values are stored corresponding to row number and later on can be manipulated to fetch just ratings or views. You may use numpy or any other library to determine the average of list of views and reviews